# Compile time error when retrieving objects from return values in a different class.

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist, return

I am receiving a compile time error with the following code.  The first code block scans in a text file and provides a get method for retrieving the largest value in the Array List.  That block of code compiles fine.  The second block of code is where I'm having difficulty.  I'm fairly new to programming and am having difficulty understanding where I've made my error.

```
    public class DataAnalyzer {

    public DataAnalyzer(File data) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    {
    List<Integer> rawFileData = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader file = new FileReader("info.txt");
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            rawFileData.add(in.nextInt());
        }
    }
    }
    }

    public int getLargest(List<Integer> rawFileData){
    return Collections.max(rawFileData);
    }

    }
```

This is the Tester Class I am attempting to implement. I am receiving a compile time error.

```
    public class DataAnalyzerTester {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter your fileName: ");              
    }

    public void printLargest(DataAnalyzer rawFileData)
    {
    rawFileData.getLargest();
    System.out.println(rawFileData.getLargest());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want to call the `printLargest` method? Otherwise, your main method doesn't do much.

Comment: maybe you should send parameters into getLargest function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tryed to run your code, you have problem in the line 14 of the DataAnalyzerTester, you need to pass a parameter of `List<Integer>` to the method `getLargest()`.

Try your Tester this way:

```
public class DataAnalyzerTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter your fileName: ");
    }

    public void printLargest(DataAnalyzer rawFileData) {
        List<Integer> example = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        example.add(0);
        example.add(1);
        example.add(2);
        int result = rawFileData.getLargest(example);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

-------------- EDIT --------------------

Try something like this:

```
    public class DataAnalyzer {

    private List<Integer> rawFileData;

    public DataAnalyzer(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        rawFileData = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                rawFileData.add(in.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }

    public int getLargest() {
        return Collections.max(rawFileData);
    }

}

public class DataAnalyzerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        DataAnalyzer analizer = new DataAnalyzer("info.txt");
        System.out.println(analizer.getLargest());
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I might have written the question in a confusing way.  I'm attempting to use the public int getLargest(List<Integer>rawFileData) from the DataAnalyzer class... in my tester class.  I'm not sure if I need to recreate the Array List, but maybe I do?

Comment: If you want to use the arraylist the you created in your DataAnalyzer you will have to change somethings, for example the scope of the variable rawFileData, i cant help you. Is that what you want?

Comment: I thought about variable scope, but I thought I could pull the data from the get method.  Do I need to create a new arraylist in the tester class?

Comment: I edited my answer for you, have a look :) Btw, you will have to have a file called info.txt inside your project

Comment: Yes, Bruno.  This works.  I'd like to pass the file name as a scanned object from the tester.  Can I create a set value in the tester class and then place that in the DataAnalyzer method?

Comment: Yes, sure. I added it for you on code by the constructor, have a look.